# Ready to use backend for mobile applications?

Tags: mobile, service, backend

for my mobile application, I am searching for a possibility to easy link all instances of this running application together (on server), but I have no experience in developing a backend server software. Thus, a ready to use "backend as a service" solution would be great.

Additionally, as I am dealing with geo-locational data, support for this kind of information (like finding others in my area) would be a benifit, too.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

Some of them are [Parse](http://www.parse.com), [StackMob](http://www.stackmob.com/), [CloudMine](https://cloudmine.me/), [Buddy](http://buddy.com/), [CocoaFish](http://www.appcelerator.com/cloud), [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/), [Kii](https://developer.kii.com/) (As told by German).

All of them support geolocation based data and offer  services on different platforms.

I have observed some of their features :

**Parse** - schema-less; Cheap;  basic analytic free; supports: push notification, user management

**StackMob** - with schema; basic analytic free; supports: push notification, user management, custom server side code

**CloudMine** -schema-less;supports: push notification, user management, custom server side code

**Buddy**: schema-less;supports: push notification, user management, friends system, has own places database,built in friends system, built in events

**CocoaFish** -  schema-less;supports: push notification, user management, built in friends system, built in events

**Kinvey** -  schema-less; supports: push notification, user management,

**Kii** - supports: push notification, user management, basic analytics free, Ad Mediation and Direct Ads

Comment: You're missing Kii http://developer.kii.com

Comment: I would add Google App Engine to the list

Comment: Another one is Backbeam https://backbeam.io It has a great control panel and all the features you need.

Comment: App42 (api.shephertz.com) is another backend provider which has multiple modules like push notification,NoSQL storage, user management, custom server side code,buddy management,avtar management etc.